# Setting linear coefficient of the Riccati equation to one

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Consider a Ricatti equation $u'=au^2+bu=0$. i.e. Riccati equation without free term and constant coefficients $a$, $b$.. Is it possible to make a linear transformation such that $b$ becomes 1? I want to find a linear transformation such that above equation becomes $u'=au^2+u$. So far, I have that it can't be done using linear transformations.

Comment: You can change $b$ by rescaling the time variable. But note that this is also a Bernoulli equation, formulating it in terms of $u^{-1}$ simplifies it immediately.

Comment: Using the change $u=v−1$, original equation in terms of v became $−v′=bv+a$. New equation has no quadratic term and can be solved analytically as a linear ODE. Thank you very much!